# Trigonometry problem of higher secondary

Tags: trigonometry

If $\displaystyle\frac{3-\tan^2\left(\frac\pi7\right)}{1-\tan^2\left(\frac\pi7\right)}
=k\cos\left(\frac\pi7\right)$, then the value of $k$ is

a. $1\qquad\qquad$b. $2$
c. $3\qquad\qquad$d. $4$

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px4Pm.jpg)

It is problem of trigonometry, and I have the solution of the problem. However, after seeing the solution, I don't quite understand how is one supposed to know how to approach this problem. My request is:

Don't just solve the problem, but also tell me from where do you come to know which approach would work. (Tell me from where do you come to know which trick or approach to be used to solution this problem.) And if  possible please give both full subjective solution and short cut method

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you make the image sideways?  So that we'd have difficulty reading it?

Comment: Applying a clockwise rotation to the computer will avoid this difficulty.

Comment: Man ,you can always tilt your head

Comment: @A---B hmm leave it, you can't help anyone with anything with that attitude.

Comment: @RaunitSingh my attitude ? what about your attitude  ?

Comment: @A---B bro just leave it , run off your business

Comment: And sorry for the sideway image to all except A..B , I will soon change that image

Comment: @RaunitSingh no need i did that. sit and relax :)

Answer (score 1):

As $\tan^2\dfrac\pi7$  resides in both numerator & the denominator,

we can replace $\tan^2\dfrac\pi7$ with $\dfrac{1-\cos^2\dfrac\pi7}{\cos^2\dfrac\pi7}$ to form a Cubic Equation$(1)$ in $\cos\dfrac\pi7$

Now observe that if $7x=\pi,4x=\pi-3x$

$\cos4x=\cos(\pi-3x)=-\cos3x$

Use [Multiple-Angle Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html) for $\cos4x,\cos3x$ to form a Bi-quadratic Equation$(2)$ in $\cos x$

Now if $\cos4x=-\cos3x=\cos(\pi-3x)$

$4x=2m\pi\pm(\pi-3x)$ where $m$ is any integer

$'+'\implies4x+3x=(2m+1)\pi\implies x=\dfrac{(2m+1)\pi}7$

$'-'\implies4x-3x=(2m-1)\pi\implies\cos x=\cdots=-1$

So, $\cos x+1$ is a factor of $(2)$

Divide $(2)$ by $\cos x+1$ and compare the resultant Cubic Equation with $(1)$